# Custom print function with _TIME_, _FILE_, _FUNCTION_, _LINE_

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.6

I have following code in **debug.h**:

```
#ifndef __DEBUG_H__
#define __DEBUG_H__

#ifdef DEBUG

int al_debug(const char *format,
        const char * time,
        const char * file,
        const char * function,
        int line,
        ...);
#define debug(fmt, args...) al_debug(fmt, __TIME__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, args...)
#else /* IF DEBUG NOT DEFINED*/
#define debug(fmt, ...) /* DO NOT PRINT ANYTHING IF DEBUG IS NOT PRESENT */
#endif /* END OF DEBUG */

#endif /* END OF __DEBUG_H__ */
```

In **debug.c**:

```
#include <stdarg.h>                                                     
#include <string.h>                                                     

#define __WRAP_FUNCTION__                                               
#include "debug.h"                                                      

#ifdef DEBUG   

int debug(const char *format,                                           
        const char * time,                                              
        const char * file,                                              
        const char * function,                                          
        int line,                                                       
        ...)                                                            
{                                                                       
    int done=0;                                                         
    va_list arg;                                                        
    va_start(arg, format);                                              
    done = vfprintf(stdout, "%s :%s:%s:%d", time, file, function, line);
    done += vfprintf(stdout, format, arg);                              
    va_end(arg);                                                        

    return done;                                                        
}           
#endif
```

And after compiling it I am getting following errors:

```
gcc -g -Wall -DDEBUG -c debug.c -o d_debug.o
debug.c:16:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
debug.c:16:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
debug.c:11:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘__FUNCTION__’
debug.c:16:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

How I can fix this problem? What is problem here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change function name

```
// int debug(
int al_debug(
```

2) Use regular `fprintf()`

```
// done = vfprintf(stdout, "%s :%s:%s:%d", time, file, function, line);
done = fprintf(stdout, "%s :%s:%s:%d", time, file, function, line);
```

3) Start at `line`.  Use parameter before `...`

```
// va_start(arg, format);
va_start(arg, line);
```

4) Pedantic note:  add `done` check for < 0 after each print.

```
done = fprintf(stdout, "%s :%s:%s:%d", time, file, function, line);
if (done >= 0) {
  int done_former = done
  done = vfprintf(stdout, format, arg);
  if (done >= 0) done += done_former;
  }
va_end(arg);
return done;
```

5) Change `args...)` to `args)`  @leeduhem

[Edit] to work with no args after format.

```
int al_debug(const char * time, const char * file, const char * function,
        int line, const char *format, ...);
#define debug(...) al_debug(__TIME__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
// @leeduhem for __VA_ARGS__
#else /* IF DEBUG NOT DEFINED*/
#define debug(...) /* DO NOT PRINT ANYTHING IF DEBUG IS NOT PRESENT */
#endif /* END OF DEBUG */

int al_debug(const char * time, const char * file, const char * function,
        int line, const char *format, ...) {
  int done = 0;
  va_list arg;
  va_start(arg, format);  // change to `format`
  ...
```

Comment: Did not helped. Did you checked it?

Comment: Edited - Compiles with `DEBUG` defined and not defined. But a problem remains hmmmm

Comment: `...` problem fixed thanks to @leeduhem  ( I  do not use variant length macros often)

Comment: But if i did not pass any argument it does not work :(

Comment: How about re-arrange `al_bug(const char * time, const char * file,  const char * function, int line, const char *format, ...)` and `debug(args...) al_debug( __TIME__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, args)`  - I'll try it.  It works!

Comment: By "no arguments", I take this to mean to augments to the "format".  The format itself is still required.

Comment: @chux This `debug(args...) al_debug(..., args)` is a GCC extension, C99 uses `debug(...) al_debug(..., __VA_ARGS__)`. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: @leeduhem Thanks for the tip. Looks like one should use `__func__` rather than `__FUNCTION__` as you did.

Comment: @chux `__func__` is part of C99, but old versions of GCC only recognize `__FUNCTION__`. [6.47 Function Names as Strings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) has more advices on proper use of them.

Comment: +1 for answer. And I will accept your answer. And to be fair with @leeduhem I will upvote his answer and two more other answer. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Phoenix The good part is that you have working solutions now.

Comment: @chux yeap. Due to yours help. Thank you. I think it can be pretty useful for all others also. Because just printing debug message is not useful with out time, file, function and line information. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version:

`debug.h`

```
#ifndef __DEBUG_H__
#define __DEBUG_H__

#ifdef DEBUG

int al_debug(const char *time, const char *file, const char *func, int line, const char * format, ...);
#define debug(...) al_debug(__TIME__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#else /* IF DEBUG NOT DEFINED*/
#define debug(...) /* DO NOT PRINT ANYTHING IF DEBUG IS NOT PRESENT */
#endif /* END OF DEBUG */

#endif /* END OF __DEBUG_H__ */
```

`debug.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>                                                     
#include <string.h>                                                     

#define __WRAP_FUNCTION__                                               
#include "debug.h"                                                      

#ifdef DEBUG   

int al_debug(const char *time, const char *file, const char *func, int line, const char *format, ...)
{                                                                       
    int done=0;                                                         
    va_list arg;                                                        
    va_start(arg, format);                                              
    done = fprintf(stdout, "%s :%s:%s:%d: ", time, file, func, line);
    done += vfprintf(stdout, format, arg);                              
    va_end(arg);                                                        

    return done;                                                        
}           
#endif
```

---

`test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "debug.h"

void foo(void)
{
    debug("debugg...\n");
    debug("%s and %d\n", "debug information", 42);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Testing:

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -I. -DDEBUG  debug.c test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12:10: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
test.c:12:22: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
$ ./a.out 
10:46:40 :test.c:foo:8: debugg...
10:46:40 :test.c:foo:9: debug information and 42

$ gcc -g -Wall -I.   debug.c test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12:10: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
test.c:12:22: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
$ ./a.out 
$
```

---

A few links that may be helpful:

[6.20 Macros with a Variable Number of Arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html)
[6.47 Function Names as Strings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Comment: It works if you pass parameters if there is no parameter it gives error :(

Comment: Is it possible to fix it? i.e.: debug("Hello world\n");

Comment: it is not possible to make it with out parameter?

Comment: @Phoenix It is possible. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: To @leeduhem. Thank you for your effort. I will upvote your 2 more answers.

Comment: Thank you once more for links.